# Parametrizing a decreasing curve

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to estimate a curve that by construction has to start from (0,0) and be decreasing. My current approach is to predict 20 numbers $d_i$ on [0, 10) as the differences between values on the curve (i.e., point 1 is at (1, $-d_1$), point 2 at (2, $-d_1 - d_2$) and so forth).

I then need to smooth this curve, and so far my best idea has been to use a quadratic* B-spline clamped at (0,0). I would like to implement this in PyTorch in the following way:

- each element in each minibatch (of size $N$) produces a set of 20 $d_i$
- for each interval between $d_i$ in each minibatch, I compute a set of coefficients
- for each element in each minibatch, I can use those coefficients to transform each of $N$ values into its corresponding point on the spline curve

The last step is the key part. I've built some fairly complicated code that slowly and unsuccessfully implements B-Splines in Pytorch. The hardest part is vectorizing it over the minibatch, which I've been totally unable to do. Is there a better way to get a simple, smooth, decreasing curve or does anyone have architectural suggestions within PyTorch?

*for...reasons it is helpful for the curve to be of order no greater than $x^2$